# getting relative path from flash.net.FileReference;

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, relative-path, filereference

I'm trying to get the relative or full path from a FileReference object after its browsed but I think I'm bashing my head up against a wall (It's begining to hurt) anybody got a way of getting a file's path from the user.

Comment: Stop hurting yourself. You cannot get the full path in flash - the file name is accessible though.

Comment: Amarghosh is absolutely correct, Adobe took measures to prevent such :(.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to switch to AIR and the flash.filesystem.File class to get the "nativePath".